# C# program not working, blank console output

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, console-application

Here is the program in which the console is blank-

```
using System;
namespace here
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double width, height, woodLength, glassArea;
            string widthString, heightString;
            widthString = Console.ReadLine();
            width = double.Parse(widthString);
            heightString = Console.ReadLine();
            height = double.Parse(heightString);
            woodLength = 2 * ( width + height ) * 3.25 ;
            glassArea = 2 * ( width * height ) ;
            Console.WriteLine ( "The length of the wood is " + woodLength + " feet" ) ;
            Console.WriteLine( "The area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square metres" ) ;
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the program where it displays output-

```
using System;

namespace here
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried uninstalling all my antiviruses, as I read in some other post. Nothing change.

Comment: are the 2 classes in the same project?

Comment: Yeah, they are in the same project.

Comment: Please remove the hello world file and try

Comment: What do you mean by `the console is blank`? `Console.ReadLine` waits for you to enter data in the console and press the enter key. The code you posted works as expected; the console is blank until you enter in data (i.e. numbers) ...

Comment: They are also in the same file.

Comment: @AJ I suggest you read a bit more on what the methods you are using do, that would help you understand why its blank and what the output was supposed to be. For example what [**`Console.ReadLine`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is correctly executing.
The console is blank because you are not print anything at the beginning of the prompt.
try this

```
    using System;
    namespace here {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double width, height, woodLength, glassArea;
            string widthString, heightString;
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter width");
            widthString = Console.ReadLine();
            width = double.Parse(widthString);
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter height");

            heightString = Console.ReadLine();
            height = double.Parse(heightString);
            woodLength = 2 * ( width + height ) * 3.25 ;
            glassArea = 2 * ( width * height ) ;
            Console.WriteLine ( "The length of the wood is " +
                woodLength + " feet" ) ;
            Console.WriteLine( "The area of the glass is " +
                glassArea + " square metres" ) ;
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the output here:
[image: Output to the code snippet above in the answer post]

Comment: Console.ReadLine();
waits for a input with an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

The line `widthString = Console.ReadLine();` waits until something is entered on the keyboard and the `Enter` key is pressed.

Enter two values for the program (the width and the height, separated by a space) and press enter for the output to be displayed.

(I'm assuming that you are new to programming in C# - hope this helps !)

Answer (score 0):

As Aniruddha Varma said, You are using Console.ReadLine(). This is waiting for you to input into the console. If you type in two numbers the program should then print. The program is paused, waiting until you type in something then press enter. The second Readline Function then does the same thing. Once two values have been entered then the rest of the function continues as you would expect. For example I put:

```
    2
    4
    The length of the wood is 39 feet
    The area of the glass is 16 square meters
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program probably workds, its just waiting for the inputs. Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting program...");   
    double width, height, woodLength, glassArea;
    string widthString, heightString;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter width: ");
    widthString = Console.ReadLine();
    width = double.Parse(widthString);

    Console.WriteLine("Enter height: ");
    heightString = Console.ReadLine();
    height = double.Parse(heightString);

    Console.WriteLine("Calculating...")
    woodLength = 2 * ( width + height ) * 3.25 ;
    glassArea = 2 * ( width * height ) ;
    Console.WriteLine ( "The length of the wood is " + woodLength + " feet" ) ;
    Console.WriteLine( "The area of the glass is " + glassArea + " square metres" ) ;
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```